# Get intersection segment between 2D line segments

Tags: 2d, collision, segment

I'm facing a problem to get the range segment when two segment lines are colliding. If they just cross each other in one point, I'm using the algorithm [provided by Gavin in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1968345/) from the book Tricks of the Windows Game Programming Gurus (2nd Edition), but this code doesn't works when the segmets overlaps in two points, like the image bellow shows.

[image]

How can I get the red segment when the lines are colliding in this situation?

Comment: Most algorithms will bail out for this, because the lines are parallel, and strictly speaking, there **is** no intersection. You'll also have to deal with some epsilon-errors, where one point would (mathematically) be **on** the line, but due to limited floating point precision, actually has a distance of 0.000021323 to the line... If this is not highly time critical (and I doubt that it is), I'd just check all four points, and if `point.distanceTo(otherLine) < 1e6` for two of them, just use these as the endpoints for the overlap segment.

Comment: Thank you. You gave me the idea: I made a function to detect if a point touches a line, so then I only need to check which points of segment A touch segment B and vice-versa.